# How to make Jetty reload its xml config files automatically?

Tags: java, jetty, jetty-9

Is it possible to extend jetty's hot deployment feature to reload, automatically, its xml config files?
I would like to make the client, through the webapp, choose to enable or disable the HTTPS service. However, for enabling/disabling, at least one xml file must be modified, which requires restarting the server. However, I would not like to restart the server when the client configure this, I would like to change it on the fly.
Is it possible? If it is, how should I configure it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create/edit/change active Connectors at runtime, do that in code, not with the XML.

Get access to the [`Server`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/) object and then CRUD the Connectors to your desired end.

See:

- [`addConnector(Connector)`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Server.html#addConnector(org.eclipse.jetty.server.Connector))
- [`removeConnector(Connector)`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Server.html#removeConnector(org.eclipse.jetty.server.Connector))
- [`setConnectors(Connector[])`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Server.html#setConnectors(org.eclipse.jetty.server.Connector[]))
- [`getConnectors()`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Server.html#getConnectors())

Comment: How can I use these functions when in the webapp? For adding a connector, I would need the Server instance, which is not accessible from the webapp.

Comment: Enabling/disabling the connectors through JMX was the solution.

Comment: Is it safe to replace Connector instances in a running server using removeConnector and addConnector?

Comment: Be conscious of the lifecycle.  Stop the connector first, then remove it.   Don't forget to start the new connector before you add it.